# User control of order of overlays in a Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

Is there a Leaflet plugin or example for letting the user control the display order of overlay layers in a map?
Turning layers on and off is working fine, but I'd like the user to be able to drag layer names within the layer control to set the Z order.

Comment: I found that Leaflet isn't explicitly setting a draw order when the initial load is done.  It draws in the order it's given layers, but if you turn a layer off then back on, it gets drawn on top.   Makes some sense from a rendering standpoint, but it's not the norm for GIS at all.  For now I can use that 'feature' to switch layer order at run time.

Answer (score 1):

For Path class (Polygons, Polylines, etc.) there are methods 'bringToFront()' and 'bringToBack()'. You can't exactly set precise position in draw order, but iterating over layer list and calling 'bringToFront()' could be less time consuming, then re-drawing every layer (especialy if they are bigger).

Comment: So the idea would be to cycle through all layers bringing them to the front, working from the bottom layer up through the top one?